# List Array - Rotate each value of Liist Array by n and keep first and last value as it is

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I need to keep first and last value of TEMP as it is in TEMP2, and all other value rotate by 4.
Ex-
TEMP's B (index=1) >>>>> TEMP2's B (index=5)

```
List<String> TEMP = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have, List Array Values in TEMP - [A, **B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N**, O]

Need new List Array TEMP2 with Values - [A, **D, G, J, M, B, E, H, K, N, C, F, I, L**, O]

```
for (int g=0; g<=TEMP.size(); g++){


}
```

---

**CLARIFICATION FROM COMMENT:**

Data is from Excel, like:

```
A  B  C
D  E  F
G  H  I
J  K  L
M  N  O
```

List was built by reading those values "by row".
OP wants the values "by column", i.e. rearranged as if the values had been read going down instead of going right.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how you create `temp2`? E.g., `C` has index 2 in `temp` but index `10` in `temp2`.

Comment: How is that a rotation? If B moved 4 places to the right, why did C move 8 places and D 13 places?

Comment: A B C
D E F
G H I
J K L
M N O

Comment: Did you mean to say each character should be shifted 4 from its immediate earlier character?

Comment: I have 3 column and 5 row in excel, I am reading value by row... a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o... but I want to insert column wise, so I need value like - A, D, G, J, M, B, E, H, K, N, C, F, I, L, O

Comment: @VaibhavJaiswal I'm beginning to understand your problem. You basically want to transpose a 5 x 3 matrix. How is the data presented in the first place? Is it in a 5 x 3 table or in a list?

Comment: I took all the cell data (which is counting/injecting by row) in array list

Comment: I think you probably need to close this question and ask another one, giving a **lot** more detail. I can't understand why you would read the data by row and then change the order so that you can write the data by column. Why not just write the data by row?

Comment: Exactly the new input given in comment "CLARIFICATION FROM COMMENT:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O");

List<String> output = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        output.add(input.get(row * 3 + col));

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O]
[A, D, G, J, M, B, E, H, K, N, C, F, I, L, O]
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not a rotation. What you're doing is multiplying indices by a constant and taking the remainder modulo 14. Rotation is when you *add* a constant modulo the size of the list. I don't know why you need this, but here is a solution.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"
);
List<String> strings2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)            
    strings2.add(strings.get((i * 3) % 14));
strings2.add(strings.get(14));
System.out.println(strings2);
```

Comment: Hello Paul, "O" is getting added after every element - A O D O...btw.. thanks, got solution !!

Comment: @VaibhavJaiswal You've typed/pasted incorrectly. Only the line `strings2.add(strings.get((i * 3) % 14));` should be in the `for` loop. This definitely works.